# How to add the checkbox selected rows to another table by clicking a button in apex

Tags: javascript, button, oracle-apex, move, apex

I have a table in my page (Region type - interactive grid) and checkboxes generated from APEX$ROW_SELECTOR.

I would like to move the rows that were selected in the checkbox to another table when the button is clicked and display a message saying "the selected rows were moved". How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

I created a button with Dynamic Action> Action : Show, Selection Type - Javascript Expression and used the following code:

```
$('button').click(function (event) {
    $("#sourcetable tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        var th = $(this);
        console.log("dfg")
        if($(th).find("input[name='link-cbx']").is(":checked")){ //assuming ids are unique remove condition if you do notwant so
            var id = $(th).find("td:eq(1)").text();
            var name = $(th).find("td:eq(7)").text();
            var type = "Type "+$("input[name='linkType']:checked").val();
            if($("#targettable:contains('"+id+"')").length < 1){            
                $("#targettable").append("<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+type+"</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](https://blog.cloudnueva.com/apex-ig-processing-selected-records), it might help

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use-case you have. What I mean is, if the interactive grid you have on your page contains only the existing table data(no editing), then in your javascript code, you can get the unique identifiers of each selected row(id, seq column etc.) and make a call to an AJAX callback where you can run a SQL query such as:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id in (apex_application.g_x01);
```

Comment: Thanks, But, I get this error message, "ORA-06550: line 1, column 76: PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values"

Comment: this is an error for example when you try to insert a record to a table with 4columns and specify 5 columns. Check the insert statement Ajax process creates by adding a log etc. Then adjust your IG accordingly